# How do i render the drawer from material UI with routing only on certain routes? (reactjs)(materialui)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-router-dom, drawer

I have a material-UI drawer in my react project, the problem is that the drawer component has the page content in the component itself. I solved a previous problem which was having routes with react-router-dom with the drawer. 
What I'm wondering how to do is I only want the drawer to show on certain routes, not all.

I've tried to make some if statements in the drawer component but couldn't find one that worked.

Routes.js

```
const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Landing} />
        <Route path='/home' component={Index} />
        <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
        <Route path='/search' component={Search} />
        <Route path='/mask' component={Mask} />
        <Route component={NoMatch} />
      </Switch>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

App.js

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavBar></NavBar>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

Small part of NavBar.js (drawer) which is where the content is shown

```
      <main className={classes.content}>
        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
        <ReactRouter></ReactRouter>
      </main>
```

*ReactRouter = routes.js

I want this NavBar.js only to show on /search and /mask but not on '/', '/home' or '/login'

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the `Component` prop to `Route`, add the component as a child. This way, you can add the `NavBar` to the routes you want like this:

(Sorry for formatting, am on mobile)

`<Route path='/mask'>
    <NavBar />
    <Mask />
</Route>`

Comment: I tried this actually but since the Mask component is "inside" the NavBar as shown above with NavBar.js, this doesn't seem to work

Comment: Then move it outside of the NavBar....Right now you're making all of the pages children of the NavBar. That's not really a great way to structure your site.

Comment: I thought so too but that seems to be the way https://material-ui.com/ does their drawer component

Comment: Yes, but that is only logical if your drawer is going to exist on ALL pages. If you are not wanting the drawer to show up, you shouldn't have it render, which means it shouldn't be the parent.

Comment: Move your routes to `App` and make your nav component a child of the components you want to show it. Otherwise, you're going to want to rethink your design.